# Datatables columnFilter plugin: not working with multiple date-ranges

Tags: jquery, datatables, filtering

Filtering works fine until I add two or more date-range filters - e. g. only one date-range column filter works fine.

When I add 2 or more date-range column filters, all filters cease to work (typing anything into any of the filters shows 0 output).

What could be the problem?

```
        var oTable = $('#sample_editable_1').dataTable({
            "aLengthMenu": [
                [5, 15, 20, -1],
                [5, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
            ],
            // set the initial value
            "iDisplayLength": 5,
            "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "oLanguage": {
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sPrevious": "Prev",
                    "sNext": "Next"
                }
            },
            "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
                //callback for fnDraw, otherwise we get an overflowed table
                //because datatables seem to update the width of the table
                //to a fixed value after redraw
                $("#sample_editable_1").css('width', '100%');
            }
            /*"aoColumnDefs": [{
                    'bSortable': false,
                    'aTargets': [0]
                }
            ]*/
        }).columnFilter(
           {
                 aoColumns: [
                                {
                                     type: "date-range"
                                },
                                {
                                     type: "text",
                                     bSmart: true
                                },
                                {
                                     type: "select",
                                     values: entities
                                },
                                {
                                     type: "text"
                                },
                                {
                                     type: "number"
                                },
                                {
                                     type: "text"
                                },
                                {
                                     type: "select",
                                     values: payment_form
                                },
                                {
                                     type: "date-range"
                                },
                                {
                                     type: "text"
                                },
                                {
                                     type: "select",
                                     values: check_status
                                },
                                {
                                     type: "text"
                                },
                                {
                                     type: "text"
                                },
                                {
                                     type: "text"
                                },
                             ]
           }
        );
```